# Stopwatch in java

Tags: java, timer, stopwatch

Im trying to make a stopwatch in java, that looks like so 00:00:00, which starts counting once a button is pressed. For some reason it won't work but I'm sure there is something that I am missing.

```
for (;;)
    {
    if (pause == false)
            {
               sec++; 

               if (sec == 60)
               {
                   sec = 0;
                   mins++;
               }
                   if (mins == 60)
                   {
                       mins = 0;
                       hrs++;
                   }

               String seconds = Integer.toString(sec);
               String minutes = Integer.toString(mins);
               String hours = Integer.toString(hrs);

               if (sec <= 9)
               {
                   seconds = "0" + Integer.toString(sec);
               }
               if (mins <= 9)
               {
                   minutes = "0" + Integer.toString(mins);
               }
               if (hrs <= 9)
               {
                   hours = "0" + Integer.toString(hrs);
               }

               jLabel3.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }
```

Comment: Or, perhaps more importantly, what does?

Comment: so each for iteration = 1 sec?

Comment: Use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for this thingy :-)

Comment: Have a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html to understand what's going wrong

Comment: I do not understand how the code simulates a stopwatch. First, the loop is tight and very fast. Each iteration may = only 1 msec. But I do not know for sure, especially when there are other applications running. Second, the loop needs to pause/sleep instead of running a very fast loop. You may want to use the class Time or Timer. Of course, if you use Timer, then you don't need to use your code for simulation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but putting this block in a `for(;;)` loop is definitely deadly.

Try something like this instead of the `for` loop:

```
// "1000" here means 1000 milliseconds (1sec). 
new Timer( 1000, new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    if( pause == false ){ 
      // ... code from above with the for(;;)
    }
  }
}.start();
```

You can read the [documentation for the timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for more information.

Comment: You can replace `pause == false` with `!pause`

Comment: i actually find ```pause == false``` nicer to read, but of course... both work just fine :)

Comment: @NominSim added the link, but this is the only constructor timer has.

Comment: The reason you're having problems is that the for loop is starving the event disatching thread, meaning nothing will ever be painted. The timer waits off in its own thread until its ready to be fired & then resyncs itself with ETD

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that an iteration is executed in much less than a second, so you gonna have "a bad time".

You'll probably need to use method like `System.currentTimeMillis()` to accurate your program,  libraries that know better how to handle [time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), or even maybe a simple sleep of 1 second in your program (but it won't be really precise).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume, (since you have offered no evidence to suggest otherwise), that this is just being executed 'as-is' from the Main-Class. You will notice that your numbers are increasing extremely fast and don't resemble a stop watch at all. Use `Thread.sleep(1000)` so a second passes between each iteration.

EDIT:
If your pause button isn't working, I will assume you're using Swing and that the button is hanging up on the event thread and not doing anything. A simple fix is to make `pause -> static` and use a `swing-worker` to execute the method your pause button is trying to initiate.